# How can I call same ISR for two different interrupts in codevisionavr?

Tags: avr, codevisionavr

I'm trying to use external interrupts `int0` and `int1` calling the same ISR.
Is there any method in codevisionAvr for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know that IDE. There might be an easy way, but a simple workaround is to put the code in another function that both ISRs call.